# HTML Search Button Enable When Someone Write A Keyword

Tags: php, html

How do I make a search button become enabled only when a user has entered text in a search field?
The button should be disabled when the search field is empty and enabled otherwise.
Here is my code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" size="100px" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Let us help you with the code you're having difficulties with.

Comment: <form action="search.php" method="get">
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" size="100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>

Comment: Please rephrase your original question, you need to describe the actual issue, instead of asking about it too broadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `<script>` tag:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input id="textField" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" size="100px" />
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="search" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<script>
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var textField = document.getElementById("textField");

    textField.onkeyup = function(){
        if (textField.value == "") {
            submitButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
            submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This script watches the text field for changes, checks if it is empty, and disables the button.

You can do this much more elegantly with jQuery.

Comment: Can you choose this answer as the accepted answer if it worked for you?